# ActionScript: Array Limitations/ How to handle lots of Data?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am running into trouble with a multidimensional array.

This works well with up to about 2000 "sets"

```
var datasets:Array = new Array(
    // one "set"
    new Array( 
        new Array( time:int, x:int, y:int, type:int ), // one "point"
                /* ... */
        /* ~70 more points */
    ),

    /* ... */
    /* ~3500 more sets */
)
```

Is there a better way to handle that many Items?

Maybe going for XML datafiles is a more convenient approach?

Comment: What is the trouble you're running into? Processing too slow, or are you talking about the trouble of actually entering or initializing the data? (If the later, what format is the data in to begin with?)

Comment: Probably it's indeed an issue with initializing the array. However with the shorthand array notation and an simpliefied structure the array of that size works fine. 

Though an issue might have been having the array definition in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a stylistic suggestion. The following:

```
new Array(x, y, z)
```

can be expressed by the shortcut syntax:

```
[x, y, z]
```

This syntax makes it easier to express nested arrays, eg:

```
[x, y, [z1, z2, z3]]
```

Now that we've got that out of the way... there really a "right" answer for your question but one thing that occurs to me is that you will have an awful lot of nested arrays in play this way. If each "set" has a fixed number of items, what about putting them in one long array and then just doing the math to determine how to retrieve the value for a given x,y position within the array. Here's what I mean, take this example of three "sets" of three values:

```
[[a1, a2, a3], [b1, b2, b3], [c1, c2, c3]]
```

Instead of nesting them you could simply store them in a flat manner like this:

```
[a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3]
```

Then when you want to retrieve a value for set 2 (zero-based it would be set "1") and value 3 (zero-based it would be value "2", you would simply access `array[setIndex * 3 + valueIndex]`

The other other thing I will say is that the structure should really be driven by the means with which you need to parse and scan through it. If you provide more information on those requirements, we could provide a better answer for you.

Comment: Ok flattening seems to really help. Defining the array in a single line was probably a bad idia, though. 

This is now working with over 4300 of those "sets". (So that enough to hold everything :)

Comment: Are you defining the data as literals within the code? If so, that definitely doesn't seem maintainable. You could easily read from a file (maybe CSV or something?).

Answer (score 0):

You could use Objects instead.

Multidimensional Arrays don't really exists in AS3 ( they do but you don't have access to most of the Array methods ).

You can't really compare having your data in an Array and having it on a data file though. It really depends on how often you need to access it, how you process it , compute it etc...

In any case you could always save your data as a JSON string, rather than XML.

```
var datasets:Array = [
    // one "set"
    // i leave the types as in your example but you 
    // would , of course , put your values instead.
    { 
        { time:int, x:int, y:int, type:int }, // one "point"
                /* ... */
        /* ~70 more points */
    },

    /* ... */
    /* ~3500 more sets */
]
```

Comment: Using a datafile was more meant to like push the issue handling data away to some proven class. I guess the XML Class is be quite optimized for large ammounts of data.

However JSON might be indeed the better choice, taking filesize and the way to import it into account.

Answer (score 0):

Creating Arrays is surprisingly performance-intensive in Flex 3. Especially if you're going to nest a huge bunch of them like that, you're going to be way better off with a different solution. A couple of suggestions depending on what you're doing with the data:

1. If you can get by storing some of it in a file or database, do that. That's what files and databases are for, after all: storing lots of data.
2. If you really need to keep everything in memory, try some more advanced collections. See if you can find a more efficient way to arrange your data using ArrayCollection or Dictionary.

Either way, you'll probably want to make a custom collectionish object for interacting with your file-db or more-advanced-collections solution. I know it's lame to do that extra work yourself, but with that much data you're really pushing past what Arrays are meant for and a custom solution is going to be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running against Flash Player 10+ you can use `Vector.<T>` instead, is significantly faster than Array for reads.

On top of that (though unrelated to FP10), I'd move your time/x/y/type to a CustomPoint class:

```
var dataSets : Vector.<Vector.<CustomPoint>> = Vector.<Vector.<CustomPoint>>([
    Vector.<CustomPoint>([
        new CustomPoint(time, x, y, type),
        new CustomPoint(time, x, y, type)
    ]),

    // ...
]);
```

Comment: I presume the Point class you mention is a custom class and not to be confused with the flash.geom.Point class?  Also, where do you get that FP10 "stores its references in contiguous memory"?

Comment: @Joony - I do indeed mean a custom point; I've changed the name of the class in my sample. One of `Vector.<T>`'s advantages, other than not requiring type coercions, is that it is immutable and represents a contiguous memory chunk. While I can't find a reference for the contiguous memory, the documentation mentions that it is significantly more performant than Array: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html - I'll change the contiguous memory reference from my post until I can find a reference.

Comment: I don't really do any writes with the data, its used once during initializiation. Generate many many tweens out of it and is never touched again after that.

However Greensock's TweenLite engine is handling all that like a charm.

So still go for vectors? (A solution using arrays is now working.)

Comment: Honestly if you've solved your performance issue another way, there's no need to move to vectors. Keep them in mind, though, if you start investigating other solutions.